# A product with different price for different product versions

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want a product with different price for different product version.

EG : A Samsung mobile in my store need to display with different mobile version attributes.  Version means same product in different countries like US, UK Saudi etc. Each version should have separate price amount.

Samsung Galaxy Note 5

- UAE Version $200
- US Version $300
- EU Version $280

How can i add different versions for a product with different price value in magento?

Comment: You can do this by making configurable product . Have you tried by making configurable product ?

Comment: Use [Custom Options](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/).

Comment: @ Dushyant Joshi  i have tried Custom Options but it will not meet my requirement. While using Custom option, price value will add with actual/base price we added to the product. I can select a price amount from  different  prices. EG : (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldknnf3nikkk0h3/new.png?dl=0)

Comment: @K.C. Can you brief me/ share me some tutorial? I am new to magento didin't know how to setup configurable product with multiple price.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you can create product with selections either via custom options or configurable product. The difference between them is that, configurable products allow you to track inventory for each of selections: UAE version, US version, EU version. If you create selections via custom option, you won’t be available to track their inventory.

What concerns product price: if selections are created with the help of custom options, their price will be calculated on the basis of main product price. For example, if you set $200 for main product and $25 for UAE version, customer will get $225 when they select UAE version at the front-end. 
When you use configurable products, you should be aware that pricing differs. Price of options will differ if you set superattribute price. You can find instructions in this post - [What Is Magento Super Attribute?](https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/magento-attribute-management/what-are-magento-super-attributes-how-to-add-super-attributes/)

Whatever you choose, you can easily manage, create, import your variations with the Magento solution - [Magento solution](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-manager-for-magento-professional-edition-1.html)

Comment: I agreed with your answer. But It is not applicable to my case. Let me explain. For Iphone6s, there are different prices in released versions UK, USA, Russian, Japanese/Hongkong. It donot be the percentage of a base amount. For EG : UK - 400$, US - 649, Japan - 1000$. So i can add custom prices for these versions not the increment or percentage of base price.